# get execution time of a single operation

Tags: apache-pig

I have a `PigLatin` script that I want to optimize.

I would like to undestand which are the most time comsuming operation.

How can I get the execution time for each Pig statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to profile the whole map-reduce cluster while running your pig script and it can be quite challenging. 
Have a look into this post: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/HowToProfile
and this: https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-5/tuning-a-job